# Is there a name for a literary genre where the main character wanders around?

Tags: single-word-requests

I remember reading about this genre on Wikipedia, but forgot what it was called. Books in this genre are wandering/doing things without purpose. There isn't really a plot, just connected small stories. It is close to [Picaresque novels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picaresque_novel), but instead of poor main character it about is a rich, carefree main character. The stories are often humorous or satiric or both.

P.G Wodehouse's *Psmith* books and others are examples of this genre.

Another detail I seem to recall is that the words has the prefix "voy" or "voyage" or something along those lines. I could remember wrong, though.

Words that are close, but not it so far are:

- Picaresque
- Milesian tale
- Travelogue
- Absurdist fiction

Comment: Do you mean a [Miliesian tale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milesian_tale)?

Comment: It's close, but not what I'm looking for. I seem to recall that the word has the prefix "voy" or "voyage" or something along those lines. But I might misremember.

Comment: All I can think of is ***voyeuristic*** but I don't think that is what you're after.

Comment: @Lambie Haha, yup, not what I'm after =)

Comment: [_Vagabond_](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vagabond) and [_vagrant_](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vagrant) both start with a "v," but I can't find any references to these words describing a type of literature.

Comment: The peripetatic protagonist, wandering protagonist.

Comment: Travelogue; itinerant protagonist.

Comment: [Absurdist fiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absurdist_fiction)?

Comment: @TotZam I think that a lot of these genres overlap, but no, that's not the word I'm thinking about.

Comment: [This page](https://www.britannica.com/art/picaresque-novel) contrasts a Picaro (poor, amoral, cynical) with a [Knight-errant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight-errant) (rich, lofty ideals, wandering) but that doesn't appear to have the humourous/satiric overtones you want. [This page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_writing_genres) has a long list of genres, but the only one with "_voy_" in is [Imaginary voyage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_voyage) which is at least described as satirical.

Comment: If not a *voyage of discovery* could you be looking for *errantry*, as in https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=errantry&rlz=1C5CHFA_enGB718GB718&oq=errantry&aqs=chrome..69i57.2319j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 ?

Comment: Could either of these be it? 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travel_literature
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_voyage

Comment: Voyageur literature is perhaps a peripatetic example.

Comment: If no suitable answer is found, I propose the use of the neology "voyalogue."

Answer (score 1):

Is what you describe [wanderings](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/wanderings)? Particular types would be the [knight-errant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight-errant), the gunslinger of Westerns, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Those could be called **odysseys**.  Named for the best known literary work of that type.

Comment: Odyssey is quite accurate *if* it is an epic journey with a serious narrative, and I can think of several great novels that could be described by that term, including certain War/ Civil War novels, but OP seems to be asking about light-hearted wanderings @GEdgar:  *"Books in this genre are wandering/doing things without purpose. There isn't really a plot, just connected small stories."*